# Grafana does not update the variable which depends on DateTime Picker

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

My Grafana dashboard variable is using the value from DateTime Picker
(data source: PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT name FROM t
WHERE dt = DATE(substr($__timeFrom(), 1, 10) );
```

The problem is: when user updates the range in DateTime Picker
this variable is not updated.

The only way to update this variable is to reload entire Grafana dashboard.

How to update this variable every time when user updates the range in DateTime Picker?

Answer (score 0):

Every Grafana variable has
"Refresh" property:
When to update the values of this variable.

Press on "On Time Range change"